# Generating functional for a chiral superfield

Tags: path-integral, supersymmetry, constrained-dynamics

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0106094v10) paper by Petrov, he writes the action of the Wess-Zumino model for a chiral superfield

$$S_J[\Phi,\bar\Phi,J,\bar J]=\int d^6z \Bigg(\frac{1}{2}\Phi\left(-\frac{\bar D^2}{4}\right)\bar\Phi+\frac{m}{2}\Phi^2+\frac{\lambda}{3}\Phi^3+J\Phi\Bigg)+h.c.,\tag{4.69}$$

where $\bar{D}_\dot{\alpha}\Phi=0$ (the condition for $\Phi$ to be chiral) has been used to write the action this way. Then he writes the generating functional

$$Z[J,\bar{J}]=\int\mathcal{D}\Phi\mathcal{D}\bar\Phi \exp\Big(i S_J[\Phi,\bar\Phi,J,\bar J]\Big)\tag{4.70}.$$

However, in $(4.70)$ we are integrating over $\textit{all }\Phi$ (and $\bar\Phi$) superfields, not only chiral (and antichiral) ones, aren't we? I would have proposed

$$Z'[J,\bar{J}]=\int\mathcal{D}\Phi\mathcal{D}\bar\Phi~\delta[\bar D_\dot{\alpha}\Phi]~\delta[D_\alpha\bar\Phi] \exp\Big(i S_J[\Phi,\bar\Phi,J,\bar J]\Big)\tag{4.70'}.$$

I'm not very used to path integral with constraints, so maybe $(4.70')$ is equivalent to $(4.70)$ but integrating just over chiral (and antichiral) superfields.

Comment: I am no expert on this at all, but as a side remark. One possibility might be writing $\Phi$ in terms of an unconstrained superfield, $\Phi=-\frac{1}{4}\bar{D}^2\phi$, and integrating over $\phi$ instead.

Comment: why do you (or the authors) denote all superfields and chiral superfields with the same letter? If Phi are chiral superfields, then $D\Phi$ would naturally mean over chiral superfields

Comment: @Kosm if $\mathcal{D}\Phi$ meant over chiral superfields, would the "gaussian integration" still hold?

Comment: @AFG the only difference between chiral and general superfield is the chirality constraint, so once you take it into account, everything holds. The paper that you linked actually explains that on page 62 and 63.

Comment: @AFG you could impose chirality as mentioned above $\Phi=-\bar D^2S/4$ and integrate over $S$, or as in that paper, use variations and delta functions defined specifically for chiral and anti-chiral superfields